# About the formation of ultra diffuse galaxies (UDGs), what are "failed L∗ galaxies"?

Tags: galaxy, terminology, formation

Recent studies show that ultra diffuse galaxies or UDGs were formed by tidally disturbed dwarf galaxies and failed L∗ galaxies.

So I've been searching for the failed L∗ galaxies but can't find what it is.

Are failed L∗ galaxies just the word that indicating Milky way like galaxies??

Comment: Can you add a link to one or more of those "recent studies"? While some people might know of some, it's better to cite the studies that you've seen so that answers can address them directly (so that you'll be discussing the same studies) and it makes the question and answer more interesting/helpful to future readers. Thanks, and *Welcome to Stack Exchange!*